# How come the Enterprise-D shows up in the Deep Space 9 finale?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

I am watching the last episode of DS9 right now, and I realized that when the Federation ships were leaving DS9 for the battle, the Enterprise-D was sitting right in the middle of the fleet.

At that point the Enterprise-D had been destroyed and the Enterprise-E had replaced it.  Was this just a mistake on the part of the CGI crew, or was it actually the Enterprise-D?

The image that I am taking about is exactly 6 minutes into the episode "[What You Leave Behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode))".

I also remember seeing the Enterprise-D in other DS9 space battles, but this is the only one that I can cite right now.

Comment: Spoiler in the question title?

Answer (score 34):

The easiest explanation is also the correct one: That wasn't the USS Enterprise NCC1701-D.

It was one of the other [Galaxy-Class ships](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galaxy_class#Dominion_War).  They, unlike the *Enterprise*, played a large part in the Dominion War.  The USS Venture even docked at DS9 during the series, traveling in concert with a few Excelsior-class ships:

[image: Venture and Excelsiors]

In the episode [Sacrifice of Angels](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_%28episode%29), for example, we see 10 Galaxy-class ships.  As the largest and most powerful class of ships in the Federation (for a time) they saw extensive use in the war, and could often be the central core around which a fleet was formed.

The war was often tough on these ships, and some were either critically damaged or destroyed in the war, such as the USS Odyssey, below.

[image: Odyssey suffering critical damage.]

All images taken from [Memory-Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Portal:Main).

Comment: Star Trek has a glorious fetish for blowing up galaxy-class starships, though usually not in the same timeline like in the dominion war.

Comment: @MarkRogers: I found it always confusing (and impressive) how fast those ships went down, despite what the Enterprise could always take. All in all, I fear DS9 had a fetish about blowing up ships the moment they got hit with anything.

Comment: @Bobby: To be fair, the Dominion ships has potent weapons.  But yeah, Galaxy classes blowing up makes for good commercials (especially during TNG, where people have to wonder if it was the *real* Enterprise).  Not to mention, the Enterprise has copious amounts of plot armor - it's basically a main character all by itself.

Comment: IIRC - the Odyssey took a beating from Dominion torpedoes, and then took two hits from kamikaze Jem'hadar ships... that's going to cause considerable damage.

Comment: @Bobby the ships would blow up as soon as they got hit with anything... Unless of course one of the main characters was on that ship, in which case it could take a WHOLE lot more.

Comment: @keegan clearly the best strategy is the spread the main characters around the most powerful ships. Disabling the escape pods would probably make it last longer too. Oh, and don't let Tasha Yar have her own ship - put another character with her, eh?

Comment: @corsiKa: Give her a ship with Wesley Crusher.  Either way, the viewers win.

Comment: Regarding the copious loss of Galaxies during the Dominion War, there is a compelling argument on reddit that the Galaxy class overall was actually a failure... or at least was not properly employed in the capacity for which it was designed. https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/1kv0r1/the_galaxy_class_was_a_failure/

Answer (score 9):

That's not the Enterprise, it's some other Galaxy-class ship.  The Enterprise was one of many of them, and they all look alike, except for the name on the hull.  In the episode where the Jem'Hadar are introduced, for example, we see one (iirc, The Odyssey) get blown up.